# Custom Cypress command doesn't return the expected value

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm writing the follow custom Cypress command in order to get the value of an element in my html page. The idea is to do this:

```
MyCompanyAPI.API.Fields.getById('main').value
```

What ist fast the same as

```
window.document.getElementById().value
```

But I need to use the first option and in a Cypress command. So I did something like that:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getValue', (id) => {

cy.window().then((win) => {
    const myCompanyAPI = win.MyCompanyAPI;
    if (!hybridForms) {
      cy.log('MyCompanyAPI object not found in window.');
      return cy.wrap(undefined);
    }
  
    return cy.wrap(myCompanyAPI.API.Fields).invoke('getById', id).then((result) => {
      const value = result && result.value;
      cy.log(`Value for ${id}:`, value);
  
      if (value === undefined) {
        cy.log(`API call for ${id} returned undefined.`);
      }
  
      return cy.wrap(value);
    });
  });
```

});

The win.MyCompanyAPI and myCompanyAPI.API.Fields really exist inside win. But when I try to call the function getByID() inside myCompanyAPI.API.Fields, the result is just:

Command:  log
index-a10e15b7.js:103972 Message:  API call for #main returned undefined.
index-a10e15b7.js:103972 Args:

I've tried in many ways. One of them like that, in order to debbug:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getValue', (id) => {

    cy.window().then((win) => {
        const hybridForms = win.HybridForms;
        if (!hybridForms) {
          cy.log('HybridForms object not found in window.');
          return cy.wrap(undefined);
        }
      
        const api = hybridForms.API;
        if (!api) {
          cy.log('API not found in HybridForms.');
          return cy.wrap(undefined);
        }
      
        const fields = api.Fields;
        if (!fields) {
          cy.log('Fields not found in API.');
          return cy.wrap(undefined);
        }
      
        const getById = fields.getById;
        if (!getById) {
          cy.log('getById not found in Fields.');
          return cy.wrap(undefined);
        }
      
        const value = getById(id);
        if (!value) {
          cy.log(`Value for ${id} is undefined.`);
          return cy.wrap(undefined);
        }
      
        const finalValue = value.value;
        cy.log(`Final value for ${id}:`, finalValue);
      
        return cy.wrap(finalValue);
      });
      
      
      
  });
```

But the result ist also: `Value for #main is undefined.`.

Could anyone here help me in this issue?

Thanks in advance!

I need to receive the value of

```
MyCompanyAPI.API.Fields.getById('main').value
```

But inside a Cypress custom command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might be passing `"#main"` as the argument to `getValue` but it expects `"main"` since `getElementById` does not need the `#` specifier. That selector syntax is only relevant to methods like `querySelector` whereas `getElementById` is already looking for IDs so the `#` discriminator is not relevant.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thanks, @adsy, to  help me to see this "detail".